# Can't install tensorflow/tfjs

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

tensorflow/tfjs just updated version, for now I can't install it
npm i @tensorflow/tfjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8gSz.png)

Could you please help? thanks!

Comment: Did you tried to install tfjs using `npm i @tensorflow/tfjs@2.1.0` ?